# Cannot install Powershell Snap-in

Tags: iis, iis-7, powershell

When executing iis7psprov_x64.msi I immedialy receive a message saying:

The PowerShell snap-in is part of Windows Operating System.  Please install it via 'Programs and Freatures' or 'Server Manager'

Extracting the msi and attempting to run it that way also yields the same message.

I am installing on Win7(64bit) with IIS 7.0.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As the error suggests, it should already be installed as part of your Windows 7 operating system.

You may need to execute (or add to your profile) the following statement to load the module:

```
import-module WebAdministration
```

Comment: I try it but I get error when I set "PS C:\>Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration"

Answer (score 1):

I think it may already be part of Window 7. In `programs and features | turn Windows features on or off | Web Management Tools | IIS Management Scripts and Tools ??`

> **System Requirements Supported
>   Operating Systems**: Windows Server
>   2008; Windows Vista Windows Vista
>   Service Pack 1 and later. Windows
>   Server 2008 and later. Windows
>   Powershell 1.0 or 2.0.
>   **Instructions** You will need to run the
>   installation package as an
>   administrator. This can be
>   accomplished by one of the following
>   methods: Logging in to your server
>   using the actual account named
>   "Administrator". Logging on using an
>   account with administrator privileges
>   and opening a command-prompt by
>   right-clicking the Command Prompt menu
>   item that is located in the
>   Accessories menu for Windows programs
>   and selecting "Run as administrator",
>   then typing the command listed below:
>   msiexec /I iis7psprov_x64.msi If you
>   already have a Beta or RC release of
>   the IIS Powershell Snap-in installed
>   the installation package will ask you
>   to uninstall this version first.

Comment: It turns out this particular feature is not necessary to load the WebAdministration module, or at least I don't have it installed. I cannot confirm whether another is required, though.