# PowerShell windows 2008 missing modules

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008

I apologize if this is a NOOB question but I wrote a PowerShell script on my windows 10 box and I am trying to run the script on a 2008 box. On the new install of the 2008 box I had to add the windows powershell feature. My end goal is to install the Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Module -ListAvailable | Import-Module
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Module -ListAvailable

ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Manifest   BitsTransfer              {}
Manifest   PSDiagnostics             {Enable-PSTrace, Enable-WSManTrace,  Start-Trace, Disable-PSWSManCombined...


PS C:\Users\Administrator>
PS C:\Users\Administrator> add-pssnapin WebAdministration
Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2.
At line:1 char:13
+ add-pssnapin <<<<  WebAdministration
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (WebAdministration:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

PS C:\Users\Administrator>
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Import-Module WebAdministration
Import-Module : The specified module 'WebAdministration' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:14
+ Import-Module <<<<  WebAdministration
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (WebAdministration:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the IIS managment tools before the `WebAdministration`-module is available. Try (tested on Win10):

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-WebServerManagementTools" -All
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows Server 2008 doesn't come with a PowerShell module for managing IIS. That feature was added with Windows Server 2008 R2. You need to [download](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/powershell) and install it first. See [here](http://windowsitpro.com/article/windows-powershell/microsoft-internet-information-services-iis-powershell-144224) for further information. See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10700660/1630171).